# Javascript for displaying day based on the date

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following set of tags:

```
<input type="text" class="form" id="reserveDate" placeholder="Select date"
       onclick="showHours(reserveDate);" onfocus="(this.type='date')" required>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

My JS code is the following:

```
function showHours(reserveDate) {
    var d = reserveDate.getDay();
    if( d >= 0){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "sunday";
    }
}
```

I am trying to debug using `CDT` and I am getting the following error message after `var d = reserveDate.getDay();`:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Is there a reason why I can not use `getDay()` here?

Comment: For some reason, showHours gets called with reserveDate being `undefined`. Try to pass correct reserveDate object to showHours.

Comment: in `onclick` you have an argument `reserveDate`, but it´s undefined.

Comment: I don't think `reserveDate` is undefined. Otherwise, the error message would be: "Cannot read property 'getDay' of undefined.".

Comment: I know that I need to call the js function with a parameter hence I called it with reserveDate which is the ID of that field, is that right thing to do? Also tried with this.getHours() but I believe I need to pass the selected value through the function.

Comment: try to use Firebug to display the content of `reserveDay` (ie. `console.log(reserveDay)`) if it really containts the object you expect there (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the inputs ID to the `showHours` function, and as all ID's are stored as `window.ID` in the global scope you're getting the HTML element, not a date object.

Remove the inline onclick handler and use proper event handlers instead

```
<input type="date" class="form" id="reserveDate" placeholder="Select date" required>
```

and then do

```
var elem = document.getElementById('reserveDate');

elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var date = new Date(this.value);
    var day  = date.getDay();

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = days[day];
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMH4N/)

Comment: Made some changes but worked as expected, thank you!

Comment: Hey I made a few changes to the code and there seems to be some problem that I am not able to figure out. Can you take a look at it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of .getDay() is probably wrong or you're passing in a wrong type of variable as reserveDate. Latter is more likely. Check with console.log(reserveDate) to see what the variable actually is and make sure its a type of Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to call the `getDate()` method inside your `showHours()` function, you should pass in a date object (instantiated from the value of you current text input), so that the callback for the click event look like the follwing: `showHours(new Date(this.value));`

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form" 
  id="reserveDate" 
  placeholder="Select date" 
  onClick="showHours(new Date(this.value))" 
  onfocus="(this.type='date')" 
  required />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Then keep your JS function as it is:

```
function showHours(reserveDate) {
  var d = reserveDate.getDay();
  if( d >= 0){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "sunday";
  }
}
```